# instance of 'std::out_of_range' error disappear with a change in expression of an integer

Tags: c++

i'm into a problem that looks like this :
Given a string s containing just the characters '(', ')', '{', '}', '[' and ']', determine if the input string is valid.

An input string is valid if:

Open brackets must be closed by the same type of brackets.
Open brackets must be closed in the correct order.

Example 1:

Input: s = "([])"
Output: true

Example 2:

Input: s = "()[]{}"
Output: true

Example 3:

Input: s = "([)]"
Output: false

Constraints:

1 <= s.length <= 104
s consists of parentheses only '()[]{}'.

the way i solve it is to put it into a for loop,and replace all the substring that look like"()","{}" with a "",an empty string. If there's no character remaining, then it should be true.

here's my code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool isValid(string s) {
        if(s.length()%2!=0)
        return false;
        else{
            int Len=s.length();
            int len=Len/2;
            int pos1=0,pos2=0,pos3=0;
            for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
                pos1=s.find("()");
                if(pos1<Len){
                    s=s.replace(pos1,2,"");
                }
                pos2=s.find("{}");
                if(pos2<Len){
                    s=s.replace(pos2,2,"");
                }
                pos3=s.find("[]");
                if(pos3<Len){
                    s=s.replace(pos3,2,"");
                }
            }
            return s.length()==0;
        }
    }
};
```

If I just run the code above, it'll report the following information:
"terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
what():  basic_string::replace: __pos (which is 18446744073709551615) > this->size() (which is 0)".

However, if I change the "pos1/2/3" in every if statement to the corresponding expression like s.find("()") , there will no longer be a problem.
Or I change the "Len" integer in every if statement to it's value--s.length(), the problem will disappear, too.
I wonder what's the difference between my code and the other two versions. I just can't figure it out cause that seems like just a equivalent transformation to me.

Comment: I strongly recommend testing `pos1` after `pos1=s.find("()");` to ensure the substring was found before trying to use `pos1`.

Comment: Looks like the judge is doing one of the first things I do: Feeding in an empty string. You should test for that. The next thing I would do is feed in the lyrics from the Major General's song from the Pirates of Penzance. This should also trigger misbehaviour in your code. Rule of thumb: Test your code.

Comment: there are constraints which i forgot to post here:Constraints:

1 <= s.length <= 104
s consists of parentheses only '()[]{}'.
i've updated the question with these words and some examples. However,it's still very nice of you guys to help me out,very humorous,good night

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::string::find` returns an unsigned integer type, `size_t`. If the string isn't found, it returns `std::string::npos` which is the largest possible value representable in `size_t`. This value is outside of the range of `int` and gets converted to the `int` value -1.

This results the condition in e.g.

```
if(pos1<Len){
```

evaluating to `true`.

The first parameter of `std::string::replace` is `size_t` and your int gets converted back to `size_t` yielding the large index value the program complains about.

if you use

```
if(s.find("()") < Len){
```

though, `Len` gets converted to `size_t` which doesn't result in any surprises, since the string length should be representable as `int` the conversion of the string length from `size_t` to `int` and back to `size_t` doesn't change the value.

Don't convert between integral types, without a good reason (or at lest be sure the values are representable in the target type of the conversion). Changing the integral types used to `size_t` should fix the issue in your program.

Note that using `auto` and comparison to the constant `std::string::npos` would be a good choice here, since you don't need to bother with the exact types. Furthermore working with `std::string::erase` is a function that better fits the operation happening here (replacing some substing by nothing).

```
auto const Len = s.length();
...
auto const pos1 = s.find("()");
if(pos1 != std::string::npos){
    s.erase(pos1, 2);
}
```

Comment: does that mean that by using erase method, there'll be less memory consumption?

Comment: @noob I just looked it up and it turns out I was wrong: `std::string::replace` doesn't make a copy. Nonetheless imho erase is the better option here. I've updated the answer...

Comment: though it says that avoid comments like"thanks", i have to say you really help me out, since this is the first time I post a question. By the way I really appreciate your suggestion of the use of erase, though I thought replace seems more intuitive to me. I really should learn to use these functions more flexibly. Good night.